# Concatenate video with no audio track with other videos containing an audio track

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a text file which contains several videos:

```
file '01.mp4' # No audio, only video
file '02.mp4' # Video with audio
...
```

All my videos are using same video codecs:

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 720x1280, 3167 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
```

And all my video that contains audio are these codecs:

```
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 43 kb/s (default)
```

I tried to add silent audio using:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i 01.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest 01-silentaudio.mp4
```

But when concatenating all my videos, it results in no audio for all videos.

Maybe I can re-encode all my video to a specific codec, including my video without sound, in order to have the same codecs for all?

What should I do?

---

**EDIT**: I tried many things, including:

Generating an empty audio and putting this audio on my no-audio video:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc=cl=mono ./dummy.opus
ffmpeg -i ./01.mp4 -i ./dummy.opus -af apad -shortest ./01-noaudio.mp4
```

and then concat all, but this give me same error.

I also tried to get the audio of one of my video in order to have same codecs, put it to my no audio video and then concat all, and even if I have no error or warning I don't have any audio after the first video.

Comment: I recommend you experiment with adding an [empty audio file to the videos without audio as explained here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1255/how-to-add-a-silenced-audio-track-to-a-video-in-ffmpeg) and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried but same output, no audio at all, with the following warnings "[mp4 @ 000001fb46a415c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 240646, current: 229307; changing to 240647. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file."

Comment: Please add the new details, including what you did to create the new empty audio tracks, to your question. Those details will be more useful when placed in the question so someone with deeper FFmpeg can see it and perhaps provide more advice.

Comment: PS: Check [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914815/117259) regarding that error.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post. I tried both solutions given in the answer, but same result...

Comment: The blank audio has to have the same attributes i.e. HE-AAC, stereo, 44100 Hz. For HE-AAC, you'll need a build with fdk-aac encoder (or audiotoolbox on Mac).

Comment: @Gyan That should be posted as an answer.